# What would "liebe ihn" and "liebe Sie" be translated to?

Tags: english-to-german

What would *liebe ihn* and *liebe Sie* be translated to? *Love him* and *love her*?

I know that *Sie* also means *they*, so can it be read as *love they*?

Comment: We need more context. Much more context. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Just a side note: The word "sie" can mean "they/them" or "she/her". The word "Sie" is the formal "you", only!

Answer (score 1):

Since you dropped the pronoun, it is not clear if *liebe* is in indicative or in subjunctive mood. But this is relevant for the translation.

Examples where *liebe* is indicative are:

> - Ich *liebe ihn*. → I *love him*.
> - Ich *liebe sie*. → I *love her / them*.
> - Ich *liebe Sie*. → I *love you*. <sub>(honorific form to a single or many persons)</sub>
> - Ich *liebe dich*. → I *love you*. <sub>(to a single familiar person)</sub>
> - Ich *liebe euch*. → I *love you*. <sub>(to many familiar persons)</sub>

Examples where *liebe* is subjunctive ([Konjunktiv I](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktiv#Konjunktiv_I)) are:

> - Er sagte, er *liebe ihn*. → He said that he *loves him*.
> - Er sagte, er *liebe sie*. → He said that he *loves her / them*.
> - Er sagte, er *liebe Sie*. → He said that he *loves you*. <sub>(honorific form to a single or many persons)</sub>
> - Er sagte, er *liebe dich*. → He said that he *loves you*. <sub>(to a single familiar person)</sub>
> - Er sagte, er *liebe euch*. → He said that he *loves you*. <sub>(to many familiar persons)</sub>

Notice that *sie* and *Sie* must be distinguished. Here, *sie* refers to the third person singular (her) or plural (them). The *Sie* with initial capital letter is the [honorific](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform) form for the second person singular or plural (you), and it replaces *dich* or *euch* used to address more familiar people.

Comment: Why can’t "Ich liebe Sie" refer to multiple persons? The honorific equivalent of "Ich liebe euch" would be "Ich liebe Sie", no?

Comment: @unor You are right. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

"Liebe Sie" may mean

1. "love you" in polite form
2. "love her" showing some big love to *H*er
3. "love you" in polite form, and also in plural
4. "love they" showing some big love to *T*hem

Forms (2) and (4) seems rare in German.

This is because the personal pronoun "sie" has many overlapping meanings. It is particularly hard to talk about on English, because also English has personal pronouns with overlapping meanings, but different ones.

Comment: In German there is a clear difference between "sie" and "Sie". I think, this is something that should be emphasized in this answer. I don't share this interpretation "Liebe Sie = love her showing some big love to Her" and only assume a spelling mistake.